# How to store category and tags separatly on wordpress?

Tags: categories, database, tags, terms

I am trying to insert data manually on all tables on the back end. I am facing a problem while inserting data to `wp_terms`. I can successfully insert category into `wp_terms` and define relationships in `wp_term_relationships` and `wp_term_taxonomy`. How does WordPress differentiate between category and tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at **wp_term_taxonomy** table you will see a column called taxonomy, categories has "category" taxonomy in the field for each category and tags has "post_tag" taxonomy, custom defined taxonomies are also working this way.